# How to load pages dynamically in the masterpage using Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, design-patterns, architecture

If I have a masterpage `SiteMaster.master`. This master page contains a dynamic menu.

How to load the pages of this menu in the content place holder of this master page using Ajax or Jquery.

---

I want to avoid full postback, Something similar to the great experience of `Gmail` for example, when i select a specific box the relevant data loaded without full postback.

Comment: I'd go to something like Vue or Angular

Comment: @hardkoded How to do it using `asp.net` :)